# Bootstrap quadratic term

Tags: bootstrap, linear-model

I have bootstrapped a linear model in PROC GLM.  Now I want to construct CI's around the parameter estimates.  For binary variables, it's straightforward: drop the reference category where the parameter estimates are zero.  However, for each replicate, the interaction of the binary term and a quadratic term produces two parameter estimates:

```
          b2*a     Est            Std err
b2*a       0      -0.0312886      0.02925361

b2*a       1      -0.0339503      0.03308580
```

It's not clear to me how to add up the replicates to obtain the mean in this case.  Normally I use PROC UNIVARIATE and capture the percentile points, but only when there is one value per replicate.  I'm not sure what to do.  Can someone enlighten me?